# How to get the last saved file name in Blender's file browser, using Blender's Python

Tags: python, file-browser

If I open Blender's file browser (in my particular case, it would be the one invoked by "Save image" in the Blender render window, "Image" menu), the filename text field will contain a value that, on the first time, is "untitled" by default.
If I save with another name, the next time that window is invoked, it will contain the last name I used.
So, I assume, Blender stores that value somewhere, even when that specific file browser is not open.
Would it be possible to read that value using python, possibly without having to invoke the file browser?
If so, would it be possible to change that value from script?
Thanks!
[image: The value in the filename text field, that's "untitled" in this screenshot, is what I'd like to read and write]